# How to refresh GameViewController from GameScene?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I successfully tested the removal of Ads after an in-app purchase. All I need is after they finalize payment, and the transaction is complete, the banner ad on the current GameScene is still there. In order to have them removed I have to relaunch the app. My GameViewController has the check in the viewDidLoad function. How do i "refresh" the viewDidLoad after the transaction is complete in the GameScene?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "doRemoveAds:", name: "RemoveAds",object:nil)
    if let scene = StartScene(fileNamed:"StartScene") {

        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("RemoveAds") == false{
        loadBanner()
    }
}

@objc func doRemoveAds(notification: NSNotification) {
    adBanner.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no need to recall viewcontroller again. You can simply do following steps.

- Let say if you are Showing Ad in ViewDidLoad method let say if you are adding it You can hide it while in some method where transaction is successful.
- If you are doing Add SubView Ads you can remove it in the method where you get transaction success notification.

**EDIT:**

**Objective C:**

First Add Observer in view controller where you controlling Ads:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doRemoveHideAds:) name:@"RemoveOrHideAds" object:nil];
```

After that in same viewcontroller Add notification method:

```
-(void)doRemoveHideAds:(NSNotification*)notification {
// Hide Or remove Ads
}
```

Now in the method where you get inApp purchase transaction Success method just call Observer like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RemoveOrHideAds" object:obj];
```

**Swift:**

First Add Observer in view controller where you controlling Ads:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "doRemoveHideAds:", name: "RemoveOrHideAds", object: nil)
```

After that in same viewcontroller Add notification method:

```
func doRemoveHideAds (notification: NSNotification){
// Hide Or remove Ads
}
```

Now in the method where you get inApp purchase transaction Success method just call Observer like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RemoveOrHideAds", object: nil)
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: The problem is, the viewcontroller controls all my gamescenes banner ad and the transaction takes place in a gamescene.

Comment: @Devbot100 than you can just add observer in that view controller & call it when transaction success

Comment: Can you add an example to your answer?

Comment: I am struggling to find the right addObserver for swift.

Comment: @Devbot100 wait i will provide you that i am using in my swift code. I will edit my answer shortly

Comment: @Devbot100 Please check my edited answer, Its working on my App made on Swift 2.0

Comment: I am having problems with the selector. I have the EXACT same line as you, and have even tried adding '@objc func' as stated in many other stack questions to fix this selector issue. Error is **Extra argument 'selector' in call**

Comment: Updated my question with my relevant code from the ViewController

Comment: @Devbot100 Please check addobserver  line carefully you forgot to add defaultCenter()

Comment: Currently punching myself... Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: I placed the postNotification in my restored and purchased case and is **terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

Comment: Make sure Method in which we did AddObserver calls first before inapp purchase